# KivyMD- KivyCamera class is initializing without being called

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, initialization, kivymd

This is my first time asking a question here so please bear with me. I'm trying to make a Camera App using opencv and kivy. I managed to do it but my problem is that the camera is being called right away even if its not on the right screen. I suspect this is because of my **init** class in KivyCamera, but I dont know any other methods to do it. What I want is that the camera will only initialize after pressing a button.

here's my main app

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, IconLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, MDList
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

import random
import string

class OneLine(OneLineListItem):
    pass

class Scr(ScrollView):
    pass

class list(MDList):
    pass

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CamScreen(Screen):
    # def show_cam(self):
    #     self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    # def mama(self):
    #     for i in range(20):
    #         self.parent.parent.ids.container.add_widget(
    #             OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
    #         )
    def on_released(self):
        # items= 
        # self.add_widget()

        for i in range(20):
            list = OneLine(text=f"dsafsd {i}", on_release= lambda list: print(list.text))
            list.text = f"dsafsd {i}"
            # list.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(list.text))
            self.ids['container'].add_widget(list)

    # pass
class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0), fps=30, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture =Texture.create(
                size = (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr'
            )
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

            self.texture = image_texture


                    
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
sm.add_widget(CamScreen(name='cam'))


class Test(MDApp):

    def on_start(self):
        size= 0.5,0.5
        # self.help.get_screen('cam').ids['cam'].add_widget(KivyCamera(size_hint = size, pos_hint = {"x":0.1,"top":1}))
        for i in range(20):
            self.help.get_screen('second').ids['container'].add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
            )

    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    random = random.choice(letters)



    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.help = Builder.load_file('tes.kv')
        screen.add_widget(self.help)
        return screen

Test().run()
```

and here's the kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    SecondScreen:
    CamScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'to second'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.current = 'second'

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'to cam'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.9}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.current = 'cam'       
    MDLabel:
        id:our_label
        text: " "
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
        # on_parent:
        #     app.samie()

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'        
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientaion: 'vertical'
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'to menu'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.95}
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'menu'

            # on_press:
            #     app.please()
                # ScrollView:
                # root.on_released()
                # list.text = list.text + "bobo"
                # root.manager.current = 'menu'
                # for i in range(4): print(f"bobo {i}")
        
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id:container
                # on_parent:
                #     app.please()     

<CamScreen>:
    name: 'cam'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        KivyCamera:
            id: cam
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1,"top":1}

            
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'show camera'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.9}
            # on_parent:
            #     app.show_cam()
```

Thanks! I really think I just need to get rid of **init** but I dont know any alternative way

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the camera update using the `on_enter()` method of `Screen`. Try changing the `__init__()` method of `KivyCamera` to:

```
class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0), fps=30, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        self.fps = fps
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)
```

And add `on_enter()` and `on_leave()` methods to `CamScreen`:

```
class CamScreen(Screen):
    # def show_cam(self):
    #     self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        cam = self.ids.cam
        self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_interval(cam.update, 1.0 / cam.fps)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.clock_event.cancel()
```

On an unrelated note, the lines:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
sm.add_widget(CamScreen(name='cam'))
```

are building the root of your `App`, but it is never used. Those lines can be eliminated.

The line:

```
self.help = Builder.load_file('tes.kv')
```

is also building the same root, and unless there is some reason for creating another `Screen` to contain that root, you can simplify your `build()` method to:

```
def build(self):
    self.help = Builder.load_file('tes.kv')
    return self.help
```

Comment: Hi @john, thanks I managed to make it work somehow with few modifications, `cam.fps`  raises an error `AttributeError: 'KivyCamera' object has no attribute 'fps'` so i just hardcoded it to 30. Now Im facing another problem, when I try to change screen it's still using my webcam. I tried using `cam.capture.release()` instead of  `self.clock_event.cancel()` inside `def on_leave` . The webcam closes now but when you go back to CamScreen it only displays a static image, maybe RefreshLayout can help?

Comment: update, I didn't notice `self.fps = fps` line that's why i'm having an error hehe :D

Comment: this answer doesn't address the problem, namely that VideoCapture is initialized before a `KivyCamera` object is created... because the VideoCapture is initialized at *definition time* of that class, because it's given as a default argument. those expressions are evaluated at definition time. I've added an answer that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def __init__(self, capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0), fps=30, **kwargs):
```

That line causes the issue.

The VideoCapture object is constructed at the time of the **definition** of the class and its method.

You probably don't want that.

Use `capture=None` in the parameter list, and in the *body* of `__init__` you should check `if capture is None: capture = cv2.VideoCapture...`